# upgrade issue Yii Framework from version 2.0.15.1 to 2.0.16.1

Tags: composer, yii

I tried installing a site I developed on my work mac (high sierra), pushed to its repo, pulled it down at home on my mac (mojave)and on running composer update get this displayed in my terminal:

```
Seems you have upgraded Yii Framework from version 2.0.15.1 to 2.0.16.1.
```

and in the browser get this

```
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
Declaration of craft\web\twig\Environment::compileSource(Twig_Source $source) should be compatible with Twig\Environment::compileSource(Twig\Source $source)
```

I tried deleting the vendor folder and running composer install but get the same, however when I delete all database tables and allow craft to reinstall it's fine (albeit no content!!!) I have no idea how to resolve this, any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the Yii message, though it may be irrelevant. The Twig message refers to an issue where Twig itself was upgraded (to 2.7.2) which broke Craft. The makers of Craft were able to publish an fix within 48 hours.

Update to the latest version of Craft, this has already been fixed.